# Base64 apache.commons .encodeBase64 symbol not found

Tags: java, encoding, base64, apache-commons-codec

I am working on writing an encryption class to encrypt/decrypt data with a key before/after sending TCP data.  I am having a problem getting `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64` to work on my system.  In most cases, I can see people relating this to android studio, however, I'm using notepad++ and the command line and am still having problems.

I have added `commons-codec-1.10.jar` to my project directory.  I run at the command line:

```
javac -cp .;commons-codec-1.10.jar Server.java ... CryptoUtil.java
```

I have this at the top

`import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;`

My error is:

```
CryptoUtil.java:60: error: cannot find symbol
               String encStr = new Base64.encodeBase64String(out);
                                         ^
    symbol: class encodeBase64String
    location: class Base64

CryptoUtil.java:87: error: cannot find symbol
                byte[] enc = new Base64.decodeBase64(encryptedText);
                                       ^
     symbol: class decodeBase64
     location: class Base64
2 errors
```

And my enclosing functions:

```
    public String encrypt(String secretKey, String plainText) 
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, 
            InvalidKeySpecException, 
            NoSuchPaddingException, 
            InvalidKeyException,
            InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, 
            UnsupportedEncodingException, 
            IllegalBlockSizeException, 
            BadPaddingException{
        //Key generation for enc and desc
        KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(secretKey.toCharArray(), salt, iterationCount);
        SecretKey key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES").generateSecret(keySpec);        
         // Prepare the parameter to the ciphers
        AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, iterationCount);

        //Enc process
        ecipher = Cipher.getInstance(key.getAlgorithm());
        ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);      
        String charSet="UTF-8";       
        byte[] in = plainText.getBytes(charSet);
        byte[] out = ecipher.doFinal(in);
        String encStr = new Base64.encodeBase64String(out);

        return encStr;
    }

     public String decrypt(String secretKey, String encryptedText)
     throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, 
            InvalidKeySpecException, 
            NoSuchPaddingException, 
            InvalidKeyException,
            InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, 
            UnsupportedEncodingException, 
            IllegalBlockSizeException, 
            BadPaddingException, 
            IOException{
         //Key generation for enc and desc
        KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(secretKey.toCharArray(), salt, iterationCount);
        SecretKey key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES").generateSecret(keySpec);        
         // Prepare the parameter to the ciphers
        AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, iterationCount);
        //Decryption process; same key will be used for decr
        dcipher=Cipher.getInstance(key.getAlgorithm());
        dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key,paramSpec);
        byte[] enc = new Base64.decodeBase64(encryptedText);
        byte[] utf8 = dcipher.doFinal(enc);
        String charSet="UTF-8";     
        String plainStr = new String(utf8, charSet);
        return plainStr;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `new` keyword expects a type to be created. As the little caret points out, there should be brackets `()` behind `Base64`.

Yet, `Base64` is a collection of `static` methods, so you are done if you just drop the `new` in this case.

```
String encStr = Base64.encodeBase64String(out);
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you.  Works.  Boy, I wasn't even close to figuring out that despite being glaringly simple :(

Comment: @Dima: I suspected that, but haven't used this commons class so far. I wanted to look it up in the `Base64` docs to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

For Android developers:

To encode:
Use `Base64.encode(yourByteArray,Base64.DEFAULT)`

To decode:
Use `Base64.decode(stringData,Base64.DEFAULT)`

make sure you import, `android.util.Base64`